# Making an operational amplifier out of a differential pair

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, small-signal

I need to modify this circuit to serve as an operational amplifier with low output resistance
[image]

Because the operational amplifier that I'm familiar with uses this differential pair:
[image]

I thought about making my former circuit single-ended so we can use a common-drain amplifier and achieve low output resistance, maybe get rid of the degenerative \$R_{ss}\$ if we wish for higher -not as linearized- gain, then it was turn to think about if we really need to have that current mirror at the top with the reference being diode-connected, for a long time I thought we only did this for current mirrors to avoid the reference transistor from entering the linear region (I found out that when we do this, the small-signal circuit also changes and \$g_{mp}\$ shows up in the transfer function). Thus, I'm reluctant about whether I should include ditching \$V_{b}\$ and making \$M_{3}\$ diode-connected in my steps of transforming the original circuit to an operational amplifier.

Comment: Have you looked into [MOSFET op-amp implementations](https://www.google.com/search?q=MOSFET+op-amp+schematic&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwjcpLu51uvuAhVL04UKHW1mCUsQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=MOSFET+op-amp+schematic&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQA1CZgwJY9ogCYKGRAmgAcAB4AIABugGIAe4DkgEDMC4zmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=EUwqYJzYAcumlwTtzKXYBA&bih=722&biw=1314&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908) at all?

Comment: We study a specific implementation from Razavi's book, it's here: https://www.docdroid.net/l1p7qvm/ec-lecture-ix-pdf#page=3

Comment: A proper opamp is much more complex with a proper output stage for example. Like Andyaka I suggest that you study real opamp designs to see what those look like and try to understand **why** in those designs, things are done as they are. Also, as a beginner, designing a "proper" opamp **is quite hard**. My prediction is that you will end up with an instable and unusable opamp. So first study what others do and understand why.

Comment: Well, you *only* need the whole buffer and output part… the differential input is only about 1/4 of the stuff needed for a whole opamp. Good luck with that